# Trouble With Validation Form Laravel with Trait (handler) and Form Request

Tags: laravel, validation

Good morning, i have a trouble.
Let me detail and i will be grateful with yours

I Have a Controller that store the resources - a trait that catch the http_error_codes (404,500) 
The trouble is when i try to save a duplicated register on the database the validator didnt work. I am validating with a Request and i want that if is a Query Exception appear a message saying "This field cant not be duplicated (for example)"

Mi Controller

```
    public function store(StoreCategory $request)
{
    $data = request()->all();
    $newCategory = Category::create($data);               
    return $this->respondCreated(new CategoryResource($newCategory)); 
}
```

My Trait

```
    public function respondCreated($data)
{
    $response = $data->response();
    return $this->setStatusCode(IlluminateResponse::HTTP_CREATED)->respond(
        $response
    );
}

    public function respond($data, $headers = [])
{
    $response = $data;
    return $response->setStatusCode($this->statusCode);        
}
```

On my trait i am validating the Status Codes, but all the duplicated registers on my DB appear like 404 because i can not validate

```
      if ($this->isModelNotFoundException($e)) {
      return $this->modelNotFound();
    } elseif ($this->isHttpException($e) && $e->getStatusCode() == 404 ){
        return $this->modelNotFound();
    } elseif ($this->isHttpException($e) && $e->getStatusCode() >= 500){
        return $this->internalError();
    } else{
        return $this->badRequest();
    }
```

My Form Request

```
    public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:50|unique:categories',
        'parent_id' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

If you can help me with anything, I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance, and excuse my English, it's not very good

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that FormRequest causes ValidationException before your controller method runs. If you wish to customize response, this is possible at app/Exceptions/Handler. Do something like:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        $errors = $exception->validator->getMessageBag();
        //some handling based on errors
    }
}
```

Another way to solve this issue is define at your FormRequest method failedValidation:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new CustomValidationException($validator, $this->response(
            $this->formatErrors($validator)
        ));
    }
```

Then define your own custom exception class with `render` method(for Laravel >= 5.5) or catch it with `instanceof` in render method of exception handler

If you want to solve problem without exceptions, you can [move validation to controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators) and create custom response based on your validation logic

Comment: Thanks its Works i make the validation on my trait with your function failedValidation and catching $e (the error)